# Can I change the background-colour of an element, when hovering over another?

Tags: html, css, hover, background-color

Is it possible to change the background of an element, when hovering over a secondary element through CSS. I want to keep the code as simple as possible.

I am looking to make the 'sup-background' element only change colour when :hover.
I know that the code below only changes the background colour of the text element.

Any suggestions or answers would be amazing, thank you.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
  a {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  
  sup {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .sup-background {
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: white
  }
  
  a:hover+.sup-background {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div><a>Hello</a><sup class="sup-background">YOU</sup></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is your HTML structure?

Comment: I do not understand exactly what you want. The box element changes background color when you hover over the text element, is this not what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using pure CSS: Add a tilde character in between the hover and target element to identify the effected element you wish to change on hover. `In CSS, the symbol tilde(~) is know as Subsequent-sibling combinator`.

[MDN General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

```css
#cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.el1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #eee;
}

.el2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: #ff0;
}

.el1:hover~.el2 {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="el1"></div>
  <div class="el2"></div>
</div>
```

This can also be achieved with Javascript using a function that incorporates two event listeners; one to change the background on `mouseover` and another to change it back on `mouseout`.

```js
let el1 = document.getElementById('el-1');
let el2 = document.getElementById('el-2');

// make a function that adds two eventlisteners  
// with two elements passed as params into the function
// paramater 1 (e) is the hover element
// parament 2 (el) is the affected element

const hoverEvent = (e,el) => {
  e.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    el.style.background = "#FF0";
  })

  e.addEventListener('mouseout',  () => {
    el.style.background = "#F00";
  })
}

// add the two parameters (elements) defined above tot he function
hoverEvent(el1, el2);
```

```css
#cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

#el-1 {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#el-2 {
  background: #f00;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div id="el-1"></div>


  <div id="el-2"></div>
</div>
```